# maya python - Place Node Along Vector

Tags: python, vector, maya

Is this the best way to go about placing an object along the vector created by two other objects in the scene? I hope you guys can help me make this more efficient as it seems very redundant and long for such a simple concept.
Thanks

[image]

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random

cmds.select(all=True)   
cmds.delete()

#------------------------------TEST SCENE SETUP

def genPos():
    x = random.uniform(-5,5)
    y = random.uniform(0,5)
    z = random.uniform(-5,5)
    return (x, y, z)

a = cmds.spaceLocator(n='ctrl_00')
b = cmds.spaceLocator(n='ctrl_00')

cmds.xform(a, t=(genPos()) )
cmds.xform(b, t=(genPos()) )

cmds.createDisplayLayer(name="Ctrls")
cmds.editDisplayLayerMembers('Ctrls', a, b)
cmds.setAttr('Ctrls.color' ,14)

cmds.select(clear=True)


#-----------------------THE SCRIPT
def normlizedVector(vecA,vecB,offset):

    nX = vecB[0] - vecA[0]
    nY = vecB[1] - vecA[1]
    nZ = vecB[2] - vecA[2]

    #vectorLength = distance vecA vecB
    # find the distance between the two supplied point3 values
    distX = pow( (vecA[0] - vecB[0] ) , 2.0 ) 
    distY = pow( (vecA[1] - vecB[1] ) , 2.0 ) 
    distZ = pow( (vecA[2] - vecB[2] ) , 2.0 )

    vecLength = sqrt(distX + distY + distZ)

    # the normalized vector is calculated by dividing the X, Y and Z coordinates by the length
    calcX = nX / vecLength
    calcY = nY / vecLength
    calcZ = nZ / vecLength

    # project point along vector, offset by a given value
    ptX = vecB[0] + (calcX * offset)
    ptY = vecB[1] + (calcY * offset)
    ptZ = vecB[2] + (calcZ * offset)

    return (ptX, ptY, ptZ)


posA = cmds.xform(a,q=1,ws=1,rp=1)  
posB = cmds.xform(b,q=1,ws=1,rp=1)  

pt = normlizedVector(posA,posB,10)

c = cmds.spaceLocator(n='main')
cmds.xform(c, t=(pt) )
posC = cmds.xform(c,q=1,ws=1,rp=1) 

cmds.distanceDimension( sp=posB, ep=posC )
```

Comment: To clarify, it's `normalizedVector()` you want more efficient? It looks pretty good to me. It could maybe be a bit more concise at the expense of clarity, but the math isn't bad.

Comment: How would I write this using normalizedVector. I tried to do this but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: How do you mean you couldn't get it to work? Were there errors? Was it in the wrong place?

Comment: My apologizes, I was confused about something else. Thank you for checking it over.